# When accessing another component's function in Angular, this keyword is not working

Tags: angular, this, angular-components, ngoninit, ngx-toastr

```
export class ComponeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private cService: CService, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  //class variable so that I can assign perticular client object
  clientObj: any;

  //to get all the client
  clients: any[] = [];

  /**
   * getting all the clients
   */
  ngOnInit() {
    this.cService.getClient().subscribe(
      (page: any) => {
        this.clients = page.payload;
      }
    );
    this.toastr.warning("Sorry, problem in loading records in client");
  }

  ....

  /**
   * Deleting particular Client
   */
  deleteClient() {
    this.cService.deleteClient(this.clientObj.id).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log('Client record Deleted!', response);
        console.log(this.clientObj.id);
        this.toastr.error("Client record Deleted");
        console.log(this.clientObj.id);
        this.ngOnInit();
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Now every `console.log` is working fine within `deleteClient` but not `this.toastr.error("Client record Deleted");` or `this.ngOnInit();` When I am clicking any other button in `sidebar component` then the toast is working.

I am calling this `deleteClint()` from another component which is in different module also.

This is in my app module

```
....
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ....
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      closeButton: true,
      enableHtml: true,
      timeOut: 5000,
      positionClass: 'toast-top-right',
    }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
```

I have tried rearranging the position where I am calling toast, as I thought it's not working after `console.log`. But it's not that. I have tried different toast positions, but that's not that problem. After `console.log` in different line, It's clear that, it's skipping lines with this keyword. AGAIN, it's not like toast is not working. Suppose this is client component opening with client button in sidebar. When I am clicking home or staff (suppose) in sidebar with sec, I can see the toast there. Otherwise never.
I have also tried assigning this keyword in a const var.

Comment: Since the `deleteClient` method is not an arrow function, you need to `bind` it to the reference of the component at where you call it. Something like `(someComponent.deleteClient.bind(someComponent))()`

Comment: You can either bind the component or create an anonymous function like `foo{ bar = () => {console.log('your function')}}` and pass that to it.